# php NumberFormater locale

Tags: php, locale

My PHP

```
$MoneyFormat = new NumberFormatter('en_US.utf8', \NumberFormatter::TYPE_CURRENCY);
print $MoneyFormat->format(5.12);
```

gives me

```
5.12E0
```

Why is that? I expect of course `$5.12`
If I change the locale-param in NumberFormater to de_DE.utf8. I get

```
5,12E0
```

locale -a

```
C
C.UTF-8
de_DE.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS / PHP 7.4.12

Answer (score 0):

The Constant for `NumberFormatter::__construct` is `NumberFormatter::CURRENCY`

```
 $MoneyFormat = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
 print $MoneyFormat->format(5.12);
```